# how to filter array with elements from another array with underscore?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have an jsonarray A but I would like to delete the elements which satisfy a certain condition. This condition is elements which have a certain id which are contained in another array called B. They both contain the same id property.

Suppose the arrays look like this:

```
A =[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]
B =[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

So the function I am trying to create would result in:

```
result=[{"id":3}]
```

I tried this but not working:

```
result= _.each(A, function(gl) {
  return _.each(B, function(tg) {
    if (tg.id != gl.id) {
      return gl;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `reject` to filter out values you don't want:

```js
var A =[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}];
var B =[{"id":1},{"id":2}];
            
var result = _.reject(A, function(item) {
   return _.find(B, {id: item.id});
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result)); // [{"id":3}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Some underscore methods you can use to check if A is in B are `find`, `findIndex`, and `where`.

Answer (score 1):

where is also fine:)

```
var A = _.reject(A, function(item) {
   return _.where(B, {id: item.id}).length > 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/moL7ts6v/)

```
var result = jinqJs().from(A).not().in(B, 'id').select();
```

Comment: jinqJs link brings to a survey.